# Xamarin MvvmCross Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: exception, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, unhandled-exception

Does anyone know how to set a catch all for all exceptions raised from a Xamarin Android app which uses MvvmCross. I have tried the solution in this [article](http://xandroid4net.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-capture-unhandled-exceptions.html) but I am still getting the unhandled exception in Visual Studio and the exception handler code is never executed.

I am just using a demo app to explore the features of MvvmCross V5.4, so I don't want to hook into hockey or anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I was trying to add exception handling in my MainActivity. What I should have been doing was creating an Application class as per this [example](https://github.com/Xandroid4Net/MyExamples/blob/master/UnhandledExceptionExample/UnhandledExceptionExampleApplication.cs).